# Passing through MongoDB document value to EJS table

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mongodb-native

I'm fairly new to node.js and MongoDB so bear with me. I have a form which stores details into a MongoDB collection; I then query this using .findOne (for now). I'm basically trying to pass this value into my index.ejs file and display it as part of the table. So the table should appear:

Name: Connor in the web browser.

My code for querying the database:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('admin/index');

    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/tickets", function(err, db) {
        // Ensure we have connected
        if(err) {
            console.log("Cannot connect to database");
        } else {
            console.log("Connected to database");
        }
        // Create a collection to query
        var collection = db.collection('tickets');
        collection.findOne({name:String}, function(err, item) {
            // Ensure we have found the ticket
            if(err) {
                console.log("There was a problem finding the ticket.");
            } else {
                console.log("Ticket found!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My code generating the table:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you render the page after you've retrieved the document, then you can pass the document or some of its properties onto the template by doing something like the following. You can try it out by putting it in the callback to the `findOne()`.

```
res.render('admin/index', { name: item['name'] });
```

Then you will be able to access it from your EJS template as follows:

```
<td>
    <%= name %>
</td>
```

If you want more information, you might want to have a look at [this tutorial](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/31/how-to-use-ejs-in-express/).

Comment: I am not exactly JS-savvy, however there is an unclosed `{` that makes me itch in your code excerpt: could it be a typo ?

Comment: @MatthieuM., absolutely. It was a typo and it has been fixed. Thanks for pointing it out!